# Installing Nexus in GCP based Ubuntu instance

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, nexus, nexus3

I am trying to install Nexus on a Ubuntu VM instance in GCP.

I am fairly new to both GCP and Ubuntu and was following [this tutorial](https://epma.medium.com/install-sonatype-nexus-3-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-562f8ba20b98) to achieve the same:

1. Installing Java:

---

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk openjdk-8-jre
```

2. Downloading, Extracting and Installing Nexus:

---

```
$ cd /opt
$ sudo wget https://download.sonatype.com/nexus/3/latest-unix.tar.gz
$ sudo tar -zxvf latest-unix.tar.gz
$ sudo mv /opt/latest-unix.tar.gz /opt/nexus
```

3. Creating Nexus User:

---

```
$ sudo adduser soumav
```

4. Giving Permission to Nexus User (soumav)

---

```
$ sudo chown -R soumav:soumav /opt/nexus
$ sudo chown -R soumav:soumav /opt/sonatype-work
$ sudo vim /opt/nexus/bin/nexus.rc
```

5. Modify memory settings:

---

```
$ sudo vim /opt/nexus/bin/nexus.vmoptions
```

6. Configuring Nexus to run as a service

---

```
sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/nexus.service
```

and copying the below content:

```
[Unit]
Description=nexus service
After=network.target
[Service]
Type=forking
LimitNOFILE=65536
User=soumav
Group=soumav
ExecStart=/opt/nexus/bin/nexus start
ExecStop=/opt/nexus/bin/nexus stop
User=soumav
Restart=on-abort
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

6. Starting Nexus

---

```
$ sudo systemctl enable nexus
$ sudo systemctl start nexus
$ sudo systemctl status nexus
```

**However**, I am having issues with a **couple** of **steps**:

1. In **step '4'** while executing this command : `$ sudo vim /opt/nexus/bin/nexus.rc`, I get a */opt/nexus/bin/nexus.rc"
   [Permission Denied]*. I am able to get past this and able to edit the nexus.rc file
   as well as nexus.vmoptions by cd-ing to the bin directory.
2. In **step '6'** when I do a `$ sudo systemctl enable nexus` and post
   that, try to start the service: `$ sudo systemctl start nexus`, I get
   a (`$ tail -f /opt/sonatype-work/nexus3/log/nexus.log`):

   ```
   Jul 29 17:16:26 nexus systemd[5832]: nexus.service: Failed to execute command: Not a directory
   Jul 29 17:16:26 nexus systemd[5832]: nexus.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /opt/nexus/bin/nexus: Not a directory
   ```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is on step #2. Last command moves the compressed file and not the uncompressed folder to `/opt/nexus`. That's the reason of your error :

`Jul 29 17:16:26 nexus systemd[5832]: nexus.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /opt/nexus/bin/nexus: Not a directory`

The correct commands for step #2 should look like this:

```
$ cd /opt
$ sudo wget https://download.sonatype.com/nexus/3/latest-unix.tar.gz
$ sudo tar -zxvf latest-unix.tar.gz
$ sudo mv /opt/nexus-3.32.0-03 /opt/nexus
```

Once you move the correct uncompressed folder to the right folder, you can follow the tutorial